# return all the values in a function

Tags: c

This is probably an easy one but my brain is fried from all this. For the function below i want to return all the rocks that are equal to 2 and not just the first one. This just prints the first rock thats equal to 2 it finds.
Thanks in advance

```
void view_drilled_rocks()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<totalRocks;i++){
        if (rocks[i].rock_completed==2){
                printf("Rock No.  Geoligist  Drill(Y/N)    Due date or comp date\n");
                printf("%d \t   %s  \t %d  \t%s", rocks[i].rock_rover_number, rocks[i].geoligist, rocks[i].rock_completed , rocks[i].due_date);
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you mix tabs and spaces?

Comment: Better indentation would have ensured that you did not encounter this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `return 0;` statement from the block.

Furthermore, a void function should not `return` a value.

Comment: that sends it on an infinite loop

Comment: Why would it? `i` starts at `0`, is incremented once in each loop and stops at `totalRocks`.  Not an infinite loop IMHO.

Comment: It can be undefined behavior, you should have asked about that problem instead, but you need to post the rest of the code. Also, if you were to use compiler warnings the fact that your function returns a value and it's declared as  returning `void` i.e. not returning a value, would have been pointed out.

Comment: What compiler would not complain about this?

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement should not be inside the `if` block. Also, the return type for your function is `void`. It should not be returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to PRINT all the rocks, remove the `return 0;` as already mentioned before.
2. If you want to return the matching rock objects, you must make a ' collection' (eg: array) of the found objects and return them in your function (not using void and really returning something)